# Configuring Kafka Broker to Run with SSL in Docker Compose

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I would like to add `SSL encryption` for the Kafka broker in my Kafka setup running within Docker Compose.

Currently I have configured  brokers,
example:

```
environment:
  
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094"

  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"

  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3

  KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3

  KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 2
```

I have assigned individual DNS for each Kafka node from **nginx**, and it is working fine.

However, the problem arises when I disable ports 9092-9097. In such cases, we encounter a **'no broker available'** error. The connection should be made through port **443**.

I want to configure access to Kafka nodes using port 443 instead of allowing individual ports.

Answer (score 0):

Docker isn't really relevant here, and Nginx doesn't "do DNS".

Kafka is not an HTTPS service, so using port 443 is just confusing. Also, Kafka clients must connect to individual brokers, therefore Nginx should not reverse-proxy to them.

If you want an HTTPS interface, then run Kafka REST Proxy project, then you can point Nginx or other solutions like Apache Knox at that for authentication. Then you can choose to only expose the HTTP server and terminate TLS at that, then forward through PLAINTEXT traffic to the brokers. Note: this will be slower than raw Kafka client protocol as you'll introduce a bottleneck / single point of failure.